# how to print a div with jsPDF?

Tags: jspdf

```
      downloadPDF() 
      { 
          var pdf = new jsPDF();
          pdf.text = document.getElementById('resume').innerHTML
          pdf.save('info')
        }
    }
```

I try to print this div but it do not work,only show blank page

Answer (score 0):

You can use html2canvas in combination with jspdf, which will convert your HTML into canvas, then save it as pdf:

```js
const myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");

html2canvas(myDiv)
  .then((canvas) => {
      const canvasData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);
      const canvasWidth = canvas.width;
      const canvasHeight = canvas.height;
      const pdf = new JsPDF("", "pt", "a4");
      pdf.addImage(canvasData, "PNG", 0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight, "", "FAST");
      pdf.save("myPdf.pdf");
    }
  )
```